# Create more than 1 turtles on patchset

Tags: netlogo

How to create more than 1 turtles on patchset such that no two turtles have the same center?

Number of turtles to create defined as density.

Therefore, I require more agents per patch.

Eluciadtion: There a a set of patches in shape of box in which I wish to fill agents. Equivalent to distributing agents in a room.

This answer [Distribute turtles on patches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575964/distribute-turtles-on-patches) would create turtles outside the box as well.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distribute turtles on patches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575964/distribute-turtles-on-patches)

Comment: I don't understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: Abhishek, you are the one who should elaborate what your requirements are. Your question is vague and could be interpreted many different ways.

Comment: Please define how density controls the number of turtles. For example: "varies from 0 to 1, where 1 means 1 turtle per patch" "D varies from 0.01 to 100.0 where D is the average number of turtles per patch", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming patchset means all the patches.

```
 Crt number
 [Setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
```

Gives you a number of turtles uniformly distributed on the patches with a very small chance of having the same center. The birthday problem with floating points.

Or this if you want n turtles uniformly distributed on any set of patches P.

```
Repeat n [ask one-of p
                       [
                       Sprout 1
                            setxy (pxcor + random-float 1 - .5) (pycor + random-float 1 -.5)
                      ]
]
```

Pick a random member of your set and put a turtle on a random part of that patch

Comment: Though I am now facing a problem dissimilar from the above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690556/check-if-turtles-have-same-x-coordinate-and-y-coordinate-as-patches . Please see if possible for you to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `density` is literally the number of turtles to create and `my-patches` is your patchset:

```
ask n-of density my-patches [ sprout 1 ]
```

If `density` is the fraction of patches that should have turtles on them (e.g. `density = 0.5` would mean half the patches should have turtles):

```
ask n-of (density * count my-patches) my-patches [ sprout 1 ]
```

If `density` should be treated probabilistically (e.g. `density = 0.5` would mean each patch has a 50% chance of having a turtle):

```
ask patches with [ random-float 1 < density ] [ sprout 1 ]
```

Comment: Above you say density as a fraction of patches. But I require more agents per patch.