# Check if turtles have same x-coordinate and y-coordinate as patches

Tags: netlogo

I have a patchset `subtractset` and some of patches have turtles on it.

Now, I wish to create turtles on only those patches which have different `x-cor` and `y-cor` as the patches.

Note: 
This is different from below code:

```
  distribute-turtles (population * percent) subtractset with[count turtles-here = 0]
```

*as here a turtle maybe on patch and still have different `x-cor` and `y-cor` as the patch.*

Thanks.
Please let me if there is some ambiguity in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patches have integer coordinates so one way would be to check if the turtles coordinates are integers.
     round xcor = xcor and round ycor  =  ycor

Is true iff the turtle is centered on a patch

Or because turtles have access to patch variables

```
 xcor = pxcor and ycor = pycor
```

Which is more pleasing to my eye and probably faster.

You could put it in a procedure.

```
To-report centered 
    Report xcor = pxcor and ycor = pycor
End
```